# Is it against the rules for tennis players to wear cleats on a grass court?

Tags: tennis, wimbledon

Watching Wimbledon, I saw Novak Djokovic and Venus Williams slip on the court.  I'm sure there were many other instances in the past of players slipping.

Can tennis players wear shoes with cleats/studs/spikes on grass courts when they play so they don't slip and/or injure themselves while playing?

Maybe it doesn't have to be cleats like soccer or football players but I've worn softball cleats with rubber spikes on a grass softball field and they help with traction on the field.  I can't see why it wouldn't help on a grass tennis court other than it's against the rules.

Comment: In British English a cleat is part of a boat.  The word makes no sense in terms of tennis shoes.

Comment: @Chenmunka In American English, [a cleat is a stud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleat_(shoe)). The word makes perfect sense in terms of sports shoes; this site is international and we can accept common international terms.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: I feel like there are plenty of moments in matches when players slide to reach the ball. Cleats would remove this ability and possibly injure just as many players because they would be stopping too quickly instead of slipping over because they are sliding too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wimbledon, as with the other Grand Slams, is governed by its own set of regulations separate from the ATP (men's) and WTA (women's) professional circuits. I can't find the exact regulations for Wimbledon, but the [2022 ATP Rulebook](https://www.atptour.com/-/media/files/rulebook/2022/2022-atp-rulebook_21dec.pdf) contains the following (Section VII, (b)(i), page 204):

> Shoes shall not cause damage to the court other than what is expected during the normal course of a match or practice. Damage to a court may be considered as physical or visible, which may include a shoe that leaves marks beyond what is considered acceptable.

That's a bit handwavey, but I think it's pretty clear this will rule out cleats/studs. Certainly, a grass court isn't going to stand up to two weeks of people playing on it with cleats.

Comment: At one point in the 2023 commentary on the BBC, it was mentioned that Rod Laver played one Wimbledon match in the 1960s wearing running spikes.  He was admonished by the All England Club and it wasn't repeated.  Whether the commentator's memory is correct, I cannot confirm.